# ElasticSearch equivalent to SQL "WHERE (condition1 OR (condition2 AND condition3))"

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to transform the SQL query below into ES syntax :

```
WHERE (id IS NULL OR (id IS NOT NULL AND test = 0))
```

I guess I have to use the "should" keyword somewhere and maybe the filter, but I'm not quite sure how to make the query in ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": [
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "test": {
                  "value": 0
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```